# Выводит ошибку This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот что конкретно выдает в консоле после набора в терминале  NMP INSTALL

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! chat@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the chat@0.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-04-05T08_21_27_467Z-debug.log

```
var http  = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var config =  require('./config/config');

var win  = require('winston');
var session = require('express-session')

var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var users = require('./Module/Users');

var users = require('./routes/users');

var MySQLStore = require('connect-mysql')(session),options  = {
config:{
    database: config.mysql.database,
    user: config.mysql.user,
    password: config.mysql.password
 }
};





var app = express();


app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/template'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('port', config.port);





app.use(session({
secret: 'supersecretkeygoeshere',
store: new MySQLStore(options),
cookie:{

    path: "/hEllo"
 }
}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.use(cookieParser());


 app.use(function (req,res,next) {
 req.session.firstname = "Anton";
 req.session.lastName = "Prohrorov";

console.log(req.session);
next();
});

app.get('/',function (req,res,next) {
res.render('index',{
    body: "<b>Hello World</b>"
});
next();
});

app.get('/chat' ,function (req,res,err) {
    Alert(req.cookie().name);
});






   http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function (req,res) {
console.log("Yes");
console.log(__dirname  + "/public");
win.info('Server listen port = ' + app.get('port').toString());
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [После запуска npm install выводит ошибку npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809897/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-npm-install-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-npm-err-this-is-probably-not-a-problem)

Comment: и зачем вы сам сервер тут вкладываете, если проблема с `npm install`?

Comment: Потому что я не совсем понимаю,где именно причина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
npm config set unsafe-perm true

npm cache clean --force
```

А потом:

```
npm install
```